# Prevent javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div onclick="AutogeneratedMethod()">
<span>SPAN 1 : I require auto method </span>
<span onclick="DesiredMethod()">SPAN 2 : I do not require auto method</span>
</div>
```

In the above code sample, how do I prevent calling the `AutogeneratedMethod()` when the user clicks on the `SPAN 2`? I do not have any control on the declaration of the `div` and its respective `onclick` behavior. That line is auto-generated from the framework I am using.

I'm looking for something that would kill Javascript execution at the end of the `DesiredMethod()`. Something like this:

```
function DesiredMethod() {
//Do necessary stuff
exit; //Abort any further Javascript
}
```

Comment: execute invalid code, it will totally prevent any further JavaScript :)

Comment: Is there any jQuery somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to stop [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation). IE has [cancelBubble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could also just move things around a bit like this:

```
<div>
   <span onclick="AutogeneratedMethod()">SPAN 1 : I require auto method </span>
   <span onclick="DesiredMethod()">SPAN 2 : I do not require auto method</span>
</div>
```

Then you wouldn't need to worry about event propagation and bubbling.

You may also want to consider attaching your JavaScript events via a different mechanism either with a framework(jQuery, etc...) or with pure JavaScript. Doing it via HTML attributes is frowned upon for many reasons. Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) for more details.

Comment: It is not under my control. The div & its onclick I mentioned here is generated by JSF.